# Logstash check connected clients

Tags: logstash, filebeat

I have a log forwarding pipeline consists of filebeat and logstash. Somehow, they stopped working together recently. How can I check if Filebeat is correctly connected to Logstash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your Filebeat log file, default location: `/var/log/filebeat/filebeat`

Example of errors:

`ERR Failed to publish events
Connecting error publishing events (retrying): dial tcp x.x.x.x:5044: getsockopt: connection refused`

Extra:
[Troubleshooting Filebeat and Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/1.1/connection-problem.html)

Comment: Thank you, `/var/log/filebeat/filebeat` does not necessary exists but you gave me the right idea.